# Find the files and folders in Google Workspace Shared Drives shared with external users

Tags: google-drive-shared-drive

It's been bugging me for ages that as a Google Workspace user, I can't search Shared Drives using Google Drive to find the *external users* with whom I have shared files and folders. This is essential as at the end of a project I need to clean up my shares and remove external users' access to my organisation - but how to find them has been a real challenge.

When the email address being searched for is not in the organisation, the Advanced Search option to filter by "Shared to" or "Shared with" specific users - that appear as the following search terms simply don't work with Shared Drives.

to:user1@company.com
sharedwith:user1@company.com

Answer (score 2):

However, here is a lesson in trying simple things. If you just search for the email address of the person then you DO get an (apparently) complete list of all the files and folders that have been shared with that user in Shared Drives. All you have to do is search in Google Drive for the email address without the search term and you get exactly what you need.

user1@company.com

This behaviour does not, however, appear to be documented anywhere useful! Please let me know if this works for other users, and I hope you find this useful.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, which seems to show who is the *owner*. However, it is still not clear how to see which files and folders certain users have Viewer, Commenter, Contributor or Content manager permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Check App Script below. It save me a lot of time to get all files and shared permission.

```golang
/*

  ======================================
  Who Can See Your Files in Google Drive
  ======================================

  Written by Amit Agarwal on 01/11/2014
  Tutorial :: http://labnol.org/?p=28237

*/

function ScanGoogleDrive() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  var timezone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  var file, date, access, url, permission;
  var privacy, view, viewers, edit, editors;

  var rows = [['File Name', 'Who has access?', 'Date Created']];

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    file = files.next();

    try {
      access = file.getSharingAccess();
      permission = file.getSharingPermission();
      viewers = file.getViewers();
      editors = file.getEditors();

      view = [];
      edit = [];

      date = Utilities.formatDate(file.getDateCreated(), timezone, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm');
      url = '<a href="' + file.getUrl() + '">' + file.getName() + '</a>';

      for (var v = 0; v < viewers.length; v++) {
        view.push(viewers[v].getName() + ' ' + viewers[v].getEmail());
      }

      for (var ed = 0; ed < editors.length; ed++) {
        edit.push(editors[ed].getName() + ' ' + editors[ed].getEmail());
      }

      switch (access) {
        case DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE:
          privacy = 'Private';
          break;
        case DriveApp.Access.ANYONE:
          privacy = 'Anyone';
          break;
        case DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK:
          privacy = 'Anyone with a link';
          break;
        case DriveApp.Access.DOMAIN:
          privacy = 'Anyone inside domain';
          break;
        case DriveApp.Access.DOMAIN_WITH_LINK:
          privacy = 'Anyone inside domain who has the link';
          break;
        default:
          privacy = 'Unknown';
      }

      switch (permission) {
        case DriveApp.Permission.COMMENT:
          permission = 'can comment';
          break;
        case DriveApp.Permission.VIEW:
          permission = 'can view';
          break;
        case DriveApp.Permission.EDIT:
          permission = 'can edit';
          break;
        default:
          permission = '';
      }

      view = view.join(', ');

      edit = edit.join(', ');

      privacy +=
        (permission === '' ? '' : ' ' + permission) +
        (edit === '' ? '' : ', ' + edit + ' can edit') +
        (view === '' ? '' : ', ' + view + ' can view');

      rows.push([url, privacy, date]);
    } catch (e) {
      Logger.log(e.toString());
      Logger.log(file.getName());
    }
  }

  var html = '<p>File Permissions Report for Google Drive</p>';

  html += '<table><tr><td><b>' + rows[0].join('</b></td><td><b>') + '</b></td></tr>';

  for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
    html += '<tr><td>' + rows[i].join('</td><td>') + '</td></tr>';
  }

  html +=
    "</table><br>For help, refer to this <a href='http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-drive-access/28237/'>online tutorial</a> written by <a href='https://ctrlq.org/'>Amit Agarwal</a>.";

  MailApp.sendEmail(email, 'Google Drive - File Permissions Report', '', { htmlBody: html });
}
```

[source by labnol](https://www.labnol.org/code/19538-file-sharing-permissions)

Comment: Thanks for the code. I'm sure it'll be useful.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a native way to find the files and folders to which certain users have Viewer, Commenter, Contributor or Content manager permissions, my workaround, to remove a user from everything, is

1. Add the user with Content Manager permission to the root folder - they momentarily get access to everything.
2. Immediately remove the users' Content Manager permission in the root folder. All their permissions are revoked from all subfolders and files.